# Integrate function $f(x,y) = y^2$ in $x^2+4y^2 \leq a^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

I am asked to integrate function $f(x,y) = y^2$ in $x^2+4y^2 \leq a^2$

To do that using polar coordinates, how may I find the boundaries for $r$? Is there a procedure that always works (for ellipses and circles)?

I know that the boundaries for $\theta$ are $0$ and $2 \pi$ therefore I must set up an integral

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{\cdots}^{\cdots} \cdots r dr d\theta$$

Is there a procedure that always works (for ellipses and circles)?

Comment: you can always make a change of variable and transform the integration domain to a circle, which is more friendly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide both sides of the inequality by $4$ to get 
$$\dfrac{x^2}{4} + y^2 \le \frac{a^2}{4}.$$

Then let $x = 2r\cos\theta$, $y = r\sin\theta$.  So now you have:
\begin{align}
  \frac{x^2}{4} + y^2 &\le \frac{a^2}{4}\\[0.3cm]
  \frac{4r^2\cos^2\theta}{4} + r^2\sin^2\theta &\le \frac{a^2}{4}\\[0.3cm]
  r^2\left(\cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta\right) &\le \frac{a^2}{4}\\[0.3cm]
  r^2 &\le \frac{a^2}{4}
\end{align}

This means 
$$ r \le \frac{a}{2}. $$

Because we also have $r \ge 0$ in general, and because $y^2 = r^2\sin^2\theta$, and because [Carl Gustav Jacob Jacobi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant), the integral is now
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{a/2} r^2\sin^2\theta \cdot 2r \, dr \, d\theta.$$

Let me know if you require further assistance.

Comment: this is not right. You forgot the Jacobian.

Comment: Thanks.  I knew that was just too pleasant.  Updating now...

Comment: @tilper thank you again friend! Best Regards, Bruno

Comment: You're welcome!